# Using SQL*Plus from command line

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have a small vbscript to load data and process it using sqlldr and sqlplus. I have 2 questions about sqlplus usage though:

1) Can I exec a stored procedure without using an .sql script file?
e.g. sqlplus user/pass@server @exec proc_myname

2) Can I use .sql script files on a shared UNC path?
e.g. sqlplus user/pass@server @\server\path\script.sql

I've tried playing around and at the moment am working around the problem by using a local temp directory to store the sql files. But I'm curious if there's another/better way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I exec a stored procedure without using an .sql script file?

Yes. I don't know VisualBasic good enough but the basic principle is that you create the child process for `sqlplus` and then send the commands via stdin (i.e. you have your script write to standard input of the child process).

> Can I use .sql script files on a shared UNC path?

If the path is correct, then that should work. You can also try I/O redirection:

```
sqlplus user/pass@server < \\server\path\script.sql
```

The drawback of this approach is that the error messages won't include the .sql script name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I wasn't having much luck with the UNC path, but I'll keep trying - as long as I know it's possible I'm quite happy to trying :)

Comment: Maybe the code uses the wrong Windows API. Have you tried mapping the share to a drive letter?

Answer (score 0):

Re your second question:

Running a script from a UNC path works for me without drive mapping or I/O redirection:

```
sqlplus /nolog "@\\server\path\file.sql"
```

sqlplus version 12.2.0.1
The quotes and '@' are important, apparently.